# Website for Ipad every click weird black squares

Tags: ipad, hyperlink, web, click, flicker

I'm making a website for ipad, a black square always appear when I click any links or javascript buttons on my website a black square box flash and flicker around the button for 0.7-1 seconds , anybody has the same problem, very annoying if my button is big, the black square is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255,0,0,0);
```

This will disable the black square correctly

Comment: hey man... you can edit your above answer.. why you post another Answer..... Stackoverflow have update facility ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control this using `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`. If you'd prefer to disable visible feedback on links altogether, use `-webkit-touch-callout: none`.

Comment: I used the high light color can change the black square box color to red, but the touch callout didnt work, the square still there even I applied it to all div span section ul li body html a...Also , do you know why everytime I pinch zoom my webpage, my webpage freeze for a second then the background flash and flicker for a second and looks like refreshing,loading my background square to square ,after a second it comes to normal?

Comment: Try using -webkit-tap-hightlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)

Comment: You will need to show us code to give you help with your other question.

Comment: my code is quite too long to show here, I don't know what can make it, but I suspect it is related to overflow, coz I wrap my whole page using a div with overflow-y:scroll,width and height 100%.I already searched in google, I tried using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch, can't help. -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px); is useless too, then I try  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
and  -webkit-transform  : translateZ(0); 
all useless... :( it dont have any problem in my macbook! I dont think it related to my javascript, coz I remove all of them the problem is still there

Comment: Did you try -webkit-tap-hightlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)?

Comment: yes rgba works . but I'm working on my flickering pinch problem now

Comment: Without code or a link, I don't think anyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what causing the problem in my code, although I don't know why is that, I have to remove 'overflow-y:scroll' and overflow-x:hidden in my code to prevent pinch zoom flickering problem. I use overflow-x hidden because element break through my container div if user resize the webpage very small, and use touchpad to scroll horizontally, will see element break through and blank areas, now I can't use overflow-x hidden coz of this weird stupid pinch zoom flickering

```
     #viewport{
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      overflow-y:scroll;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
   #wrapper{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
   }
```